# Datagrid not refreshed when bound datatable is modified using another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datatable

Scenario: 
There is a datagrid bound to datatable in View Model. This datatable reference is injected to Model and it is updated using a background thread.

Result:
Datagrid is not immediately refreshed as soon as underlying datatable is updated but if I switch between different tabs then datagrid is showing latest values present in datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach would be to start a **[background task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd321439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** for updating the datatable async and hook up on finishing this operation with `.ContinueWith` to update the UI.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ..Do the background DataTable update.. })
            .ContinueWith(task => {.. Update the UI.. });
```

But you have to **[dispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh199416%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** the `.ContinueWith` action into the Main Thread, due to the STA restriction.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ..Do the background DataTable update.. })
                .ContinueWith(task => 
                             {
                                var dispatcher = Application.Current == null
                                     ? Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher
                                     : Application.Current.Dispatcher;

                                Action action = delegate()
                                                {
                                                    //Update UI (e.g. Raise NotifyPropertyChanged on bound DataTable Property)
                                                 };

                               dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, action);
});
```

Since the Dispatching operation is a repeating operation I would suggest to put the logic into a ViewModelBase Class to reduce the code like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ..Do the background DataTable update..)
            .ContinueWith(task => Dispatch(() =>
                {
                    //Update UI
                }));
```

To Update the UI you can use the common notify of INotifyPropertyChanged to raise the property changed event on the bound datatable.